# why does this keyword in a regular function return window object when calling it inside a class method?

Tags: javascript, function, class, this, class-method

Why hello function return window object?
Shouldn't it return App object?
hello function is a regular function and it is supposed to return the object that calls it.

```
<body>
  <button id="btn">Click Me!</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>
  <script>
    function hello() {
  return this
  }
  class App {
    constructor() {
      
    };
    a() {
      return hello()
    }
  }
  console.log(new App().a())
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `hello()` invokes it with no `this`, so it's the global object or `undefined`

Comment: In non strict mode, `this` is assigned to default to global